# Merge tags: post-production, postproduction, post

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonym-request

[post](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/post) and [postproduction](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/postproduction) should be merged (and synonymized) with [post-production](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/post-production).

Comment: Great catch.  Thanks.